# Updating a value that is passed through a class' parameter

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have been tasked to build a questionnaire using JFrames. I have created a class which can take a question number as a parameter and return the question, the answers and the correct answer to the specified question.

Below is some very basic idea of what my code is like

```
int qNum = 1;
QnA questions = new QnA(qNum);
JFrame frame = new JFrame;
JLabel q = new JLabel(QnA.question)//where the .question returns the question determined by qNum.
JRadioButton ans1 = new JRadioButton(QnA.Answers[0])//.Answers[] is the array in which the answers are stored.
JRadioButton ans2 = new JRadioButton(QnA.Answers[1])
//etc
JButton sub = new JButton("Submit");
Jbutton rst = new JButton("Clear");
```

Then I created an event handler which will increment the value of qNum if the answer is correct.

```
if(qNum >0 && qNum<20){
   qNum ++;
frame.revalidate();
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You have the completed the quiz!");
    qNum = 1;
}
```

I am trying to update the question number(qNum) being passed through the parameter. I understand that java gets results by value rather than by reference, so me updating the value later in the code does not actually update. I was wondering if there was a way that this can actually be done?

Thanks!

Comment: One option would be to return a value from the event handler.  This would allow to pass back the question number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class to hold the value and then update it.

```
class SimpleClass{
    int qNum = 1;
}

SimpleClass qClass = new SimpleClass();
```

Then just pass the object in and update the qNum property. (FYI, if you do something like `qClass = new SimpleClass();` inside the method that you pass qClass  to, it will create a new object and you'll lose your reference to the object).

Comment: Wow thank you! Thanks to what you said about creating qClass inside another method, I was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Let me make a disclaimer by saying that I think there is a better design to the problem that you are trying to solve and ultimately, it would be better to improve it.

As to your question, basically what you need to do is to create a class that will represent the counter:

```
class QuestionsAnswered {
    private int count = 0;

    void increment() {
        count++;
    }

    int currentCount() {
        return count;
    }

    boolean hasAllQuestionsAnswered() {
        return count > 0 && count < 20;
    }
}
QuestionsAnswered questionsAnswered = new QuestionsAnswered();
QnA questions = new QnA(questionsAnswered);

if (questionsAnswered.hasAllQuestionsAnswered()) {
    questionsAnswered.increment();
    frame.revalidate();
}
```

Note, that some related logic like the number of questions comparison may and in my opinion should be incapsulated within that class.

Comment: unfortunately even when I pass this through, it does not work :/. I know there are probably better ways to do this. Unfortunately as it's almost deadline time, I can't come up with anything as a new java student...